# How to find harmonic average speeds from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, date, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of speeds in KmH, and a column of timestamps:

```
Date,                     Speed
2016-07-07 13:38:02.000,  50.718590
2016-07-18 11:28:00.000,   2.357645
2016-07-15 15:03:08.000,  14.652172
2016-07-18 06:53:00.000,  24.530390
...                       ...
2016-07-18 18:41:31.000,  31.761416
2016-07-14 05:28:42.187,   7.532758
```

What I want is to have a [harmonic average speed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_mean) for each 15 minutes in an average day:

```
Time,  Speed
00:00, 32
00:15, 10
00:30, 12
00:45, 41
01:00, 12
...
23:30, 30
23:45, 31
```

My initial attempt was to remove the dates from each timestamp, set it as the index, and use TimeGrouper to find the average. (My dataframe is called output) The code was:

```
output['Speed'] = output['Speed']**-1
output['Date'] = output['Date'].apply( lambda d : d.time() )
output = output.set_index(['Date'])
output = output.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('15Min')).mean()
output['Speed'] = output['Speed']**-1
```

The code didn't work however as it gave me an error:

```
 Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'
```

Comment: Can you try without the first line where you change your datetimes to time only, so just `output = output.set_index(['Date'])
output = output.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('15Min')).mean()`

Comment: It doesn't create an error, however it creates an average speed for every 15 minutes from the first date to the last date, whereas what I want is every day averaged into one.

Comment: OK, one thing you could do is normalise the date by doing this `pd.to_datetime(df['date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))` this will set the date to be the same for all entries, then you can do what you were doing before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is normalise the dates, then you do the resampling:

```
In [177]:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
df

Out[177]:
                 Date      Speed
0 2017-02-07 13:38:02  50.718590
1 2017-02-07 11:28:00   2.357645
2 2017-02-07 15:03:08  14.652172
3 2017-02-07 06:53:00  24.530390
4 2017-02-07 18:41:31  31.761416
5 2017-02-07 05:28:42   7.532758
```

now all dates are same, by default today's date, then do what you want:

```
In [178]:
output = df.set_index('Date')
output = output.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('15Min')).mean()
output['Speed'] = output['Speed']**-1
output

Out[178]:
                        Speed
Date                         
2017-02-07 05:15:00  0.132754
2017-02-07 05:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 05:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 06:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 06:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 06:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 06:45:00  0.040766
2017-02-07 07:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 07:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 07:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 07:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 08:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 08:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 08:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 08:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 09:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 09:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 09:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 09:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 10:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 10:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 10:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 10:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 11:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 11:15:00  0.424152
2017-02-07 11:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 11:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 12:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 12:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 12:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 12:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 13:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 13:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 13:30:00  0.019717
2017-02-07 13:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 14:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 14:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 14:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 14:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 15:00:00  0.068249
2017-02-07 15:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 15:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 15:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 16:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 16:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 16:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 16:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 17:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 17:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 17:30:00       NaN
2017-02-07 17:45:00       NaN
2017-02-07 18:00:00       NaN
2017-02-07 18:15:00       NaN
2017-02-07 18:30:00  0.031485
```

so this:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

what this does is to extract as a string just the time using [`dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), we can then use `to_datetime` to make a datetime64 series where all dates are the same